# Match non-capturing group multiple times

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I tried really hard to make a good title, but I'm not sure if I'm asking this right. Here's my best attempt:

**I'm using Python's flavor of regex**

I need to match numbers using named groups:

```
15x20x30    ->  'values': [15,20,30]
15bits      ->  'values': [15]
15          ->  'values': [15]
x15         ->  'values': [15]
```

but should not match:

```
456.48
888,12
6,4.8,4684.,6
```

my best attempt so far has been:

```regex
((?:[\sa-z])(?P<values>\d+)(?:[\sa-z]))
```

I'm using `[\sa-z]` instead of a word-boundary because `15x20` are two different values.

**But** it fails to match both `15` and `20` for the `15x20` case. It does work if I put an extra space as in `15x 20`. How do I tell it to "reset" the non-capturing group at the end so it also works for the non-capturing group at the beginning?

Comment: Use `(?<=[\sa-z])(?P<values>\d+)(?=[\sa-z])` or just ``(?<=[\sa-z])\d+(?=[\sa-z])`` since you do not really need the named group here. The best is ``(?<![^\sa-z])\d+(?![^\sa-z])`` that will also match at the start/end of the string (not sure you need that functionality).

Comment: That works really well! I failed to match the start of the string with the lookbehind but really didn't think of this! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<![^\sa-z])\d+(?![^\sa-z])
```

Case insensitive version:

```
(?i)(?<![^\sa-z])\d+(?![^\sa-z])
```

Or, compile the pattern with the `re.I` / `re.IGNORECASE` flags.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yxHQqH/1)

**Details**

- `(?<![^\sa-z])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left, there is no whitespace or a lowercase letter (any ASCII letter if `(?i)` or `re.I` are used)
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?![^\sa-z])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right, there is no whitespace or a lowercase letter (any ASCII letter if `(?i)` or `re.I` are used)